# How to render game in 3d anaglyph

Tags: 3d, directx, render, anaglyph-3d

As far as I know, Nvidia supports 3d Anaglyph driver.

But what I want is render 3d Game in 3d Anaglyph for user instead of install driver.

I am looking for techniques or document about this.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the context, but a common way is to use a postprocessor shader with the colors of the chosen anaglyph and zbuffer, if you are the developer of the game (is part of the program, if you are a gamer you can not do much just by installing drivers)